# Having trouble IntelliJ IDE's auto-completion completing with a spacebar instead of a Tab

Tags: java, ide, intellij-idea

I was typing in IntelliJ IDEA 11.1.1 code and I typed in the word

```
public class AnimalTestDrive{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        MyAnimalList list = new MyAnimalList();
        Dog a = new Dog();
        Cat
    }

}
```

but when I went to put in a space it keep auto-completing with this:

```
public class AnimalTestDrive{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        MyAnimalList list = new MyAnimalList();
        Dog a = new Dog();
        Catalog
    }

}
```

I've spent a couple hours trying to find where to stop this behavior since I want to only auto-complete using Tab. Anyone else experienced this?

Because apparently I am too new, I can't answer my own question but I did figure it out.

Solution: I have managed to resolve this issue. There is an options located under ***File*** > ***Settings...*** > ***Editor*** > ***Code Completion*** > Change ***Preselect the first suggestion:*** From ***Smart*** to ***Never***.

Comment: Hi, what idea version do you have?

Comment: I just figured it out, but StackOverflow says I'm too new to answer my own question for another 7 hours. :-( Thank you for following up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior can be disabled:

[image: preselect]

Another option is to increase **Autopopup code completion** delay.

Comment: Thank you. I figure this out a second before people started providing answers and I couldn't scramble fast enough to make the point that I figured it out. Thank you for providing the solution here none the less. You guys are awesome.